# Why is my stop button not working on this javascript audio player?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, audio-streaming

Okay, hello people. I have a simple audio player here in which the play button and the pause button work, but not the stop button. Since the pause button works, can I somehow just repeat the pause function but set the song to start again at 0.00 time and use that as my stop button?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Audio</title>
</head>
<body>

<script>
function play(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.play();
             }

    function stop(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.stop();
             }

    function pause(){
   var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
   audio.pause();
             }



</script>

<input type="button" value="PLAY"  onclick="play()">

  <input type="button" value="STOP"  onclick="stop()">

  <input type="button" value="PAUSE"  onclick="pause()">


  <audio id="audio" src="i_am.mp3" ></audio>

  <audio id="audio" src="311.mp3" ></audio>

  <audio id="audio" src="thievery_corporation.mp3" ></audio>

  <audio id="audio" src="saxy.mp3" ></audio>

  <audio id="audio" src="silent_rider.mp3" ></audio>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#Methods
there does not exist a `stop()` function, and yes you can do that

Comment: Pause and stop are more or less the same functionality in this scenario.  And since stop() isn't a function, you should just use pause();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stop function, try pausing and setting the current time:

```
function stop() {
  const audio = document.getElementById('audio');
  audio.pause();
  audio.currentTime = 0;
}
```

See also:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime